# Getting text manually to wall post text area (Share on facebook with FB API - Android)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-wall

It seems that the "message" Post to wall field will be ignored (with reference to this link) [Facebook Feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

> This field will be ignored on July 12, 2011. The message to 
>   prefill the text field that the user will type in. To be compliant 
>   with Facebook Platform Policies, your application may only 
>   set this field if the user manually generated the content 
>   earlier in the workflow. Most applications should not set this.

I was thinking if there would be a **hack** (i mean with user request) that we could  manually to paste the text to the post to wall text box? Copying to clip board and asking user to paste it in the text field is what I am doing right now. Can this be done with an alert dialog box showing the text to be pasted to the wall text box and if YES, it will be automagically pasted to the text box. Having said that, I'm aware on how to create an alert box with the messages, **I could not find where the TEXT BOX of the POST TO WALL dialog is situated in the API.** Can some one please help me on this.!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have user consent for the text you want to post, why not get the `publish_stream` extended permission from the user and post the message directly to the API? The `message` parameter is only removed from the feed dialog, not direct posts to the `/feed` connection in the Graph API

Comment: I am using `facebook.authorize(this,PERMISSIONS,Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());` and also `facebook.dialog(this, "stream.publish", parameters, new WallPostDialogListener());` for post to wall. But the dialog is just empty.! I think i have found a solution (correct me if I am wrong) I just tried `facebook.request("me/feed", parameters,"POST");` And it works and i disabled the post to wall dialog! Is the way I am doing legal?!!

Comment: The [Platform Policies](http://developers.facebook.com/policy) require that users consent to every post made on their behalf - if this is the case (i.e you have your own interface where the user enters a message and it's clear to the user that you're going to submit that to Facebook) then you're fine - just make sure never to fill the 'message' parameter with something the user themselves didn't type